# jQueryでhtmlから取得した値をグローバル変数に代入して違うコードに渡すには？？

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

webアプリを制作しているのですが、jQueryを使ってユーザがformで入力した値を以下のように取得しました。

```
<script>
    $('button').click(function () {

        // 選択ボックス
        m = $('#minute').val();
        console.log(m);
    });


</script>
```

consoleにちゃんと入力した値が表示されるところまではきたのですが、そのあとjQueryの関数から抜けてconsoleを実行しても値が表示されません。

```
<script>
    $('button').click(function () {

        // 選択ボックス
        m = $('#minute').val();//ここにvarを付けないとグローバルになると聞いた。
        console.log(m);
    });
    console.log(m);//mは定義されてないエラーが出る。

</script>
```

return文などを使うと思うのですがJqueryを挟んでいるかで上手く代入出来ないです。
**試した事**

```
<script>
    var m = $('button').click(function () {

        // 選択ボックス
        var m = $('#minute').val();
        return m;
    });
    console.log(m);

</script>
```

何かいい方法はないでしょうか？

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jQueryファイルは上記から読み込んでいます。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: やりたいことがよく分からないのですが、外側の`console.log(m)`では意図としてなにを出力したいのでしょうか。`m`という存在しない変数を出力しようとしていますが。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascriptの変数スコープ
https://qiita.com/Kazuuuuuki/items/3c40bbe6e7bb7ff84e3e
はこちらを参考にしてもらうとしてソースとしてはグローバルなスコープにて変数を宣言してください。

```
<script>
    var m;
    $('button').click(function () {

        // 選択ボックス
        m = $('#minute').val();
        console.log(m);
    });
    console.log(m);

</script>
```

=====================
以下追記分

```js
    var m;
    $('button').click(function () {

        // 選択ボックス
        m = $('#minute').val();
        console.log(m);
    });
    console.log(m); //ここはJavascriptが読み込み時に実行されるから絶対undefined
    
    $('#console_check').click(function () {
        console.log(m);//ここはチェックリンクがクリックされたときに実行される。
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="minute" type="text" value="11" />
<button>クリック</button>

<a id="console_check" href="jacascript:void(0);">チェック</a>
```

================
追記2
Jqueryのイベントハンドラの規約になりますが、
通常returnに任意の値を返すことはできません。
return falseを返すと別の処理が入ります。
https://qiita.com/r_abe01/items/2433caa6ce5257a440e7

Comment: 上をように変更しmが定義されていないエラーはなくなったのですが、jQuery内のconsoleは実行されて外側のconsoleのmは空のままです。

Comment: jQueryの関数内でreturn文を使用して返り値をオブジェクトに代入することは出来ないのでしょうか？

Comment: 外側のconsoleが空なのはJavascriptの読み込みに実行されるから絶対空ですね。一度でもbuttonクリックイベントが走れば、 mの変数に値が入っています。追記しました。

Comment: JQueryの返り値はJqueryの仕様で決まっていますので、その旨を追記しました。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。上手く出来ました。

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $('button').click(function () { // --(1)

        var m = $('#minute').val(); // --(2)
    });
    console.log(m); // --(3)

</script>
```

結論から言うと(3)の位置で(2)の値は取れません。
他の方もおっしゃるようにjsの実行タイミングが異なるからです。

質問者さんはおそらくjsの実行タイミングを
(1)→(2)→(3)
で実行されるものと思ってらっしゃるようです。

実際には
(3)→(ボタンがクリックされる)→(1)→(2)
となります。

そのため、ボタンが押された後で、その値を使って外側で何か処理をしたいのであれば、
その処理を別関数として定義しておき、その引数として実行されるべきだと思います。

例えば、

```
<script>
    $('button').click(function () { // --(1)

        var m = $('#minute').val(); // --(2)
        outPutValue(m); // --(3)
    });
    function outPutValue(m) { // --(4)
        console.log(m); // --(5)
    }
</script>
```

とすれば、
(ボタンが押される)→(1)→(2)→(3)→(4)→(5)
の順に実行されるはずです。